# Instrumental methods of analysis

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry

I am taking the instrumental methods of analysis course. Our job is to find the unknown  mass of $\ce{Fe}$ which is added, by measuring the absorbance of different solutions with ortho-fenantroline.

Is there any way I can know if my calculated mass of $\ce{Fe}$ is correct or not?   Is there any way I can prove it, since I know the absorbances?

Answer (score 3):

Am I right that you are planning to simply calculate the $\ce{Fe}$ concentration using the Lambert-Beer equation?

The obvious proof would be to prepare $\ce{Fe}$ solutions with known concentration(s) to compare the absorbances. Using these solutions, you can also make sure that the assumption of linearity over the concentration range is actually fulfilled.

Comment: We already prepared those solutions with known concentrations, and then found the concentration of the unknown Fe solution, and then of course the mass. I found the Fe mass, but I don't know if that is the exact one. That is known only by our teacher, and we will be testet if the mass of Fe given is not that of our calculations. Hopw i was clear ...

Comment: @NdrinaLimani Then, I think you've done all one can do. If repeated measurements give identical results, there's no reason not to trust your own  work.